# How to detect timeout for S3 OperationError in golang's aws-sdk-go-v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, networking, error-handling

I have some code that uploads files to some S3 bucket via MultipartUpload. If the server is not available, the code produces errors like this:

```
operation error S3: CreateMultipartUpload, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , HostID: , request send failed, Post "http://[...]?uploads=&x-id=CreateMultipartUpload": dial tcp xx.xx.x.xxx:xx: i/o timeout
```

The error is returned by `s3.Client.CreateMultipartUpload`. Note that I'm using `aws-sdk-go-v2`.

I want to identify such timeout errors, but *only* timeout errors. To be clear, I don't want to **fix** the error, I just want to be able to identify that it happened. Is there some more elegant way of doing it other than just parsing the error string for `i/o timeout`?

Here's some ways I've tried to do it, and none of them work:

```
var oe *smithy.OperationError
if errors.As(err, &oe) {
    fmt.Printf("Attempt 1 %t\n", errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded))
    fmt.Printf("Attempt 2 %t\n", errors.Is(oe.Unwrap(), os.ErrDeadlineExceeded))
    if netErr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && netErr.Temporary() {
        fmt.Printf("Attempt 3\n")
    }
    if netErr, ok := oe.Unwrap().(net.Error); ok && netErr.Temporary() {
        fmt.Printf("Attempt 4\n")
    }
    if netErr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && netErr.Timeout() {
        fmt.Printf("Attempt 3\n")
    }
    if netErr, ok := oe.Unwrap().(net.Error); ok && netErr.Timeout() {
        fmt.Printf("Attempt 4\n")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Attempt 5 %t\n", os.IsTimeout(err))
    fmt.Printf("Attempt 6 %t\n", os.IsTimeout(oe.Unwrap()))
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with Go or the AWS SDK for it but can't you use `oe.ErrorCode()` and filter based on that? Does this help: https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/handling-errors/

Answer (score -1):

If every function call in the chain wrapped their returned errors, then this would be enough:

```
if errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded) {
    // it's an i/o timeout
}
```

However, if one call in the chain somewhere doesn't wrap the error because it's <1.10, then it won't work. If it doesn't work, there's a <1.13 function that will probably work: `IsTimeout(err)`:

```
if errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded) || os.IsTimeout(err) {
    // it's an i/o timeout
}
```

See more: https://pkg.go.dev/os#IsTimeout